# Optimized way to get sum of elements across channels in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4D `(68000, 96, 124, 4)` Tensor and I want to get sum of elements across all the channels. Below is the code I am using and it is slow. I am wondering if there is an optimized way to get this done.

Below is the code I am using.

Example:

```
TrainData = np.random.rand(20,5,3,4)

SumChannels = []
for Element in range(0,TrainData.shape[0]):
    row = []
    for channel in range(0,4):
       row.append(TrainData[:,:,:,channel][Element].sum())
    SumChannels.append(row)
```

The result is SumChannels, a nested `list` of length 20 (from the example) with every `inner list` of length 4

PS: Well, I have no idea why the above code was too slow but when I restarted my machine. The output was instant

Comment: np.sum() can take an axis parameter, are you just trying to `np.sum(arr, axis=3)`? If not, can you provide sample input and output to make a [mcve]?

Comment: You can sum along multiple axes - `TrainData.sum(axis=(1,2))`.

Comment: What should be the shape of the result?

Comment: he result is a nest list of length 68000 with every inner list of length 4